# JPA persist() method is not doing its job

Tags: jpa

I am working on a JPA, jsf2.0 Hibernate project. It is a management of the user's actions through a primefaces calendar that you can see [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf).

I managed to get user's actions and display them in the calendar, but when I want to add a new action it seems to work: I have no error message but in reality the action is not added in database. It seems like the persist method is not doing its job, it is not returning any error message so I don't know what to do to see why.

I put you here the 2 functions for these 2 actions (display and add):

Method to add an action (it does not work)

```
public void creerAction(Action action){


     Date date = action.getDateAction();
     action.setDateAction(date);



     EntityManagerFactory emf = null;


        try{
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GA2010-ejbPU-dev");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();


         em.persist(action);



        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Action  " + action.getTexteAction()+ " ajouté avec succès");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

     }catch(PersistenceException e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }



    }
```

and the method to get all actions of an user (it works)

```
public List<Action> getAllAction(){
                HttpSession sess = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);

        String codeUser =  (String) sess.getAttribute("codeUser");

        EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

        try{
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GA2010-ejbPU-dev");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();



         Query requete = em.createQuery(SELECT_ALL_ACTION);
          requete.setParameter("codeUtilisateur", codeUser);

         this.allAction= requete.getResultList();



        }catch(Exception e){

         this.message = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage())    ;
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null, message );

        }


        return allAction;



    }
```

And here is the declaration of my unit persistence

```
<persistence-unit name="GA2010-ejbPU-dev" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>dev</jta-data-source>
         <class>entities.Utilisateur</class>
         <class>entities.Action</class>
        <properties>
          <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="C:/tmp"/>
        </properties>
```

How can I see why persist does not persist and why I am not having an error message?

Comment: Probably you're not committing the transaction, and that's why you don't get an error nor the data is stored.

Comment: JPA is doing the transaction it self no? i have no transaction to write i thought?

Answer (score 0):

Persists need to be done from within a transaction.  The object is not persisted until you commit the transaction:

[Hibernate EntityManager tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html)

Comment: thank u for ur answer i hava tried to write a transaction  and got this error message => java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA. it seems i cant write a transaction?

Comment: in my persistence unit i have this=> <persistence-unit name="GA2010-ejbPU-dev" transaction-type="JTA"> if i understand well transaction-type="JTA" means that jpa is doing the transaction it self no?

Comment: I have not used JTA, and the syntax of it looks quite heavy.  I would drop JTA and use transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL".  Then you can use:

em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
// persist
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();

Comment: Well, i have tested and it is the same result , it seems to works, no error message  but in fact it does not , no action added in database...

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the persistence unit config.  Perhaps try using a simple SessionManager and scrapping the JTA for now.

Comment: hello thank u for ur answer , it workss now , the problem was linked (if i can say that ..) with cycle life of an ejb that i should have injected instead of initialising it manually..